# In emacs, how would one add the same text to multiple lines?

Tags: html, emacs, wget, aquamacs

I have an HTML file that contains a bunch of links to an entire database. But the URLs are all written as:

```
<a href=/bw/examplefile.html>
```

When I try and use wget to download all of the links, I use the --base parameter to set the URL but it doesn't seem to work all that well. So, instead of fiddling with something I know I won't use again I just wanted to know how to add a URL to each link object easily in emacs.

I'm using Aquamacs on a Mac. Not sure if that makes all too much of a difference, but it may be useful info.

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing. What do you want it to look like afterwards?

Answer (score 5):

I expect the following is what you want, to turn your relative URLs into absolute URLs (and add the attribute quotes, which is a little nicer).

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<a href=\(.+?\)>` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<a href="http://example.com\1">` <kbd>RET</kbd>